# Insert from one table to another (different databases)

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Auth2.dbo.Accounts :**  account_id, login_name , password , other columns...

**Auth.dbo.Account :** account_id , account , password , other columns...

I want to insert accounts(account_id,account,password) from "**Auth.dbo.Account**" to "**Auth2.dbo.Accounts**" (account_id,login_name , password) and giving other columns values that I want.

I was hoping that this could work , but once I wrote in SQL Management studio , I got an error syntax error near the " select account_id from Auth.dbo.account"

```
INSERT [dbo].[Accounts] ([account_id], [login_name], [password],
       [referral_id], [referral_code], [pcbang], [block],
       [withdraw_remain_time], [age], [auth_ok],
       [last_login_server_idx], [event_code], [server_list_mask], 
       [result], [ip], [game_code], [gamecode], [login_event],
       [email], [security_a_1], [security_a_2], [security_a_3],
       [security_a_4], [security_q_1], [security_q_2], [security_q_3],
       [security_q_4], [votepoints], [cash], [country]) 
VALUES (select account_id from auth.dbo.Account, N'Imad', 
               N'3cfbbd2ae3c3e416c6d00a5a12ee60e8', NULL, NULL, 
               0, 0, NULL, -1997, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
               N'::1', NULL, NULL, NULL, N'imad.lekal@outlook.com',
               NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
               0, 189, NULL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with simple [`INSERT/SELECT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp). In this case `account_id` will be from `auth.dbo.Account` and all the other values will be constants.

```
INSERT Auth2.[dbo].[Accounts] ([account_id], [login_name], [password], [referral_id], [referral_code], [pcbang], [block], [withdraw_remain_time], [age], [auth_ok], [last_login_server_idx], [event_code], [server_list_mask], [result], [ip], [game_code], [gamecode], [login_event], [email], [security_a_1], [security_a_2], [security_a_3], [security_a_4], [security_q_1], [security_q_2], [security_q_3], [security_q_4], [votepoints], [cash], [country]) 
select account_id , N'Imad', N'3cfbbd2ae3c3e416c6d00a5a12ee60e8', NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, -1997, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'::1', NULL, NULL, NULL, N'imad.lekal@outlook.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 189, NULL from auth.dbo.Account;
```

Comment: The whole first line is invalid , It says columns names are invalid since we didn't specify any database

Comment: @Dablackninja ok try now with Auth2 reference on table being inserted

Comment: Fixed that issue , one question though.
If we are selecting and giving valeus "null , null , 0,0 ...." for other columns , are we inserting them or selecting them ?

because other columns != other_columns of the other table

Comment: @Dablackninja you are creating the new rows on auth2 table with this constant values. All the rows inserted will be the same except for account_id. For example, all the rows will have `N'imad.lekal@outlook.com'`as email.

Comment: Those are my players data in the database.
I suppose your query should work but now I'm getting an error that tells me IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF , how I should set it to ON

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT auth2.dbo.Tool ON; GO `

Comment: @Dablackninja `account_id` is probably an identity column. Keep in mind that all the accounts are going to have the same email, password, login_name... I don't know if that's what you are looking for

Comment: I used the query and they don't have the same login_name & password , why would they ?
I turned it off now , If they register , the account_id should increase each time . I only used the query you gave me to merge without the need of deleting all the accounts ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `VALUES (`

When you `INSERT` using `SELECT` you should not use `VALUES`, since the values are coming from the `SELECT`

Also prefix the table names with the database names, assuming that `Auth` and `Auth2` are 2 different databases.

Finally, your `FROM` is off.

Following should work.

```
INSERT Auth2.dbo.Accounts 
(
[account_id]
, [login_name]
, [password]
, [referral_id]
, [referral_code]
, [pcbang]
, [block]
, [withdraw_remain_time]
, [age]
, [auth_ok]
, [last_login_server_idx]
, [event_code]
, [server_list_mask]
, [result]
, [ip]
, [game_code]
, [gamecode]
, [login_event]
, [email]
, [security_a_1]
, [security_a_2]
, [security_a_3]
, [security_a_4]
, [security_q_1]
, [security_q_2]
, [security_q_3]
, [security_q_4]
, [votepoints]
, [cash]
, [country]
) 
SELECT 
account_id 
, N'Imad'
, N'3cfbbd2ae3c3e416c6d00a5a12ee60e8'
, NULL
, NULL
, 0
, 0
, NULL
, -1997
, 1
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, N'::1'
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, N'imad.lekal@outlook.com'
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, 0
, 189
, NULL
FROM auth.dbo.Account
```

**PRO TIP:** Format your SQL properly bro, it helps to debug :).

Answer (score 1):

hi i think this will help you first of all you create **database link**

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK your_db_link_name
 CONNECT TO Schema_Name
 IDENTIFIED BY <PWD>
 USING 'Your Database Name';
```

next you need to make a query

```
INSERT [Accounts] ([account_id], [login_name], [password], [referral_id]
      , [referral_code], [pcbang], [block], [withdraw_remain_time], [age], [
      auth_ok], [last_login_server_idx], [event_code], [server_list_mask], [
      result], [ip], [game_code], [gamecode], [login_event], [email], [
      security_a_1], [security_a_2], [security_a_3], [security_a_4], [
      security_q_1], [security_q_2], [security_q_3], [security_q_4], [
      votepoints], [cash], [country])
      VALUES (
      select ac.account_id
      from Your_DB_Link_Name@Account ac, N'Imad', N'3cfbbd2ae3c3e416c6d00a5a12ee60e8',
      NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, -1997, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'::1', NULL,
      NULL, NULL, N'imad.lekal@outlook.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
      NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 189, NULL)
```

i think this will help you if you have any query then feel free